# "No two $0$'s together" versus "No two consecutive $0$'s"

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, combinatorics-on-words

I am solving a problem which asks: **How many $13$-bit binary numbers that have no two $0$'s together are there?**

**My first approach**: A $13$-bit binary number can

**either** start and end with $0$ like $0101010101010$ and here we can replace the $0$'s with $1$ also that is they have two choices either be $0$ or $1,$ therefore for seven $0$'s, $2^7$ choices;

**or** start and end with $1$ so for six $0$'s, $2^6$ choices.

Therefore, the solution is $2^7 + 2^6 -1=191.\;$ ($-1$ so that $13$-bit binary number with all $1$'s is considered only once.)

**My second approach**, using recurrence relation for $n$-bit binary numbers with no two consecutive $0$'s:
$$a_{n} = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}, a_0 = 1, a_1 = 2, a_2 = 3$$
so for $a_{13}$ the answer is $610.$

Comment: In your first approach you never counted $0110110110110$, for example.

Comment: @StinkingBishop why? I think I counted that in my first approach in case where it start from 0 so like this at 3rd position(from Left to right)  since there were 2 choices i.e. 0 and 1 so considering choice as 1 similarly for other places where you have mentioned 1 instead of 0 so I think have counted that. Please explain me if I am wrong.

Comment: So, the first group are $2^7$ sequences matching the pattern  $x1x1x1x1x1x1x$ and the second group are $2^6$ sequences matching the pattern $1x1x1x1x1x1x1$, where each of the $x$'s can be $0$ or $1$. The sequence $0110110110110$ matches neither of those two patterns, as it has zero in the $1$st but also in the $4$th position.

Comment: Your second approach is correct, by the way; hope you understand why the recurrence holds.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thank you so much I understood why my 1st approach didn't work. Your explanation helped a lot otherwise I would have thought of are these 2 statements different or same i.e. 2 0's not together or No 2 consecutive 0's 
since asking such doubts to Language Models like chatgpt creates a lot of confusion ☠️. Yes I understand why recurrence relation holds.

Comment: Don't ask chatgpt, plain and simple.

Comment: Last time I asked a maths question I got a “helpful” chatgpt answer that was just absolute nonsense. Another answer that someone posted here because it was so ridiculous: First line I thought “you wouldn’t solve this like that”. Second line “this can’t be right”. Third line “this is absolute nonsense”.

Comment: Asking chatgpt might have been useful if you had started from the knowledge that it might well be wrong and carefully analyzed what it suggested. But as @StinkingBishop says, just don't.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a neat way to think about this problem.

Instead of asking how many 13-bit binary numbers there are with no consecutive **0**'s we can equivalently ask how many 13-bit binary numbers there are with no consecutive **1**'s.

In the following we define the Fibonacci numbers as $F_{-1}=1$, $F_0 = 1$, $F_1 = 2$, $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$ (we care for this exact indexation).

A beautiful theorem by Zeckendorf says that every number $n$ can be uniquely decomposed into a sum of **pairwise non-consecutive** Fibonacci numbers, i.e. $n=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i F_i$ with $a_i\in \{0,1\}$ and $a_ia_{i+1}=0$ for all $i$. Taking these coefficients we can turn each number $n$ into a binary string $[n]_Z=a_ka_{k-1}\ldots a_1a_0$, where $k$ is the highest non-zero coefficient (i.e. forget all leading **0**'s). Let us call $[n]_Z$ the *Zeckendorf code* of $n$.

One quickly sees that the number of $k$-bit Zeckendorf codes is exactly $F_{k-2}$. Note that all $k$-bit Zeckendorf codes start with **10**, so the number of $(k+2)$-bit Zeckendorf codes is exactly the number of $k$-bit *binary* codes with no consecutive **1**'s (including those with leading **0**'s).

Hence, the number of $k$-bit binary codes with no consecutive **1**'s is $F_k$, in particular, for $k=13$ we get $F_{13}=610$.

---

I know that this approach is a little overkill for the problem at hand but I wanted to point out the nice mathematics connected to this. Also, there is a generalization of Zeckendorfs theorem for Narayana numbers and all the other higher-order generalized Fibonacci numbers, so that questions like *How many binary numbers with all **1**'s at least $r$ **0**'s apart are there?* can be answered analogously.